# How can I log screen sharing access on OS X?

Tags: security, leopard, screen-sharing, logs

I've got my firewall on (the OS X firewall) and I've got a lot of attempts on screen sharing.

```
Allow AppleVNCServer connecting from 93.78.170.237:2223 uid = 0 proto=6
```

I want to log successful connections to make sure no one is making it through, similar to what is done with /var/log/secure.log

In fact, I'm surprised this isn't included with secure.log

What can I do?

For what its worth, I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8.

**Update 1:**

Daniel had a nice suggestion to use

```
netstat -a | grep vnc | grep ESTABLISHED
```

redirected to a file to log what is going on.

The problem is a connection is flagged as `ESTABLISHED` as soon as the vnc login screen comes up regardless of whether or not a login is ultimately successful.

In other words, all those (hopefully) failed attempts that my firewall logs will look no different than my successful logins.

Comment: I agree the secure log in 10.5.8 does log VNC attempts, but says either FAILED or SUCCEEDED

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily extend the script that was suggested to me in another question to solve my need for [notifications when VNC connections were established](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15945/6467#15948).

Basically, replace the notification aspect of the script with a line that writes to a log file.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion but doesn't quit discriminate between successful attempts and failed attempts.

Take a look at my update above.

Answer (score 2):

Screen shares are logged in `/var/log/secure.log`