# How to run an AppleScript whenever a VNC connection is established?

Tags: applescript, remote-desktop

I want to run a script whenever any user connects remotely to my Mac.

I've Googled a bit about it but no perfect tutorial is there. I am less comfortable working with OS X.

Comment: If some file is changed on login (is there a VNC log file ?) It could be watch be the LaunchAgents and when change it could run the script !

Comment: I think [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15945/application-to-notify-user-of-active-vnc-connection) is quite similar and has already been answered.